# How to control how many letters and numbers the user enters into an input prompt?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and we were given our first assignment! My whole code is working fine, but here is my problem:

We have to prompt the user to enter in an account ID that consists of 2 letters followed by 3 digits.

So far I only have a basic input/output prompt

```
//variables

String myID;

//inputs

System.out.println("Enter your ID:");
myID = input.nextLine();
```

So all it does is let the user enter in how many letters and digits they want, in any order and length. I don't understand how to "control" the user's input even more.

Comment: You can't control the user's input. You can control how your program responds. [Somebody make this into a motivational poster.]

Comment: a way to check if the input is valid would be using a regex

Comment: @shmosel oh that makes more sense. how do i do that? we aren't taught loops or try catch statement yet

Comment: @shmosel im trying to understand how to think the logic through

Comment: @SmolCoder then you have not done regex as well... ?

Comment: You have to check, if the user input suites your requirements. E. g. you can use myID.length() to check if he entered 5 chars. Then you have to split the string and check the other things.

Comment: @Azola no i haven't ever heard of it; this is my first time

Comment: Continue your code by checking the format of `myID`, if you haven't learned regex and its for early java lessons I think checking the length is acceptable. If format is not as desired print some error message and prompt the nextLine() again

Comment: @IQV so u mean substrings?

Comment: Yes. To check if the first two chars are letters and the other three are digits, you need the method `substring()`.

Comment: @IQV so far I have this:  //Prompt the user to enter in their  id
        System.out.println("Enter your ID:");
        myID = input.nextLine();
        
        //check length of string
        length = myID.length();
        
        //if length = 5
        if (length = 5)
          
        //if length > 5
        if (length > 5) 
          
        //if length < 5
        if (length < 5)

Comment: @IQV it wont let me format my replies :(

Comment: You could edit your question. But I think, first you should learn the basics of java. That is how to define a variable and assigning new values, how to compare values, what are loops and how can they used...

Comment: A `Scanner` – I assume you're using a `Scanner` – is not designed to restrict the user's input. You can, however, parse the user input. The easiest way is to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), well, you have to learn them anyway.

Comment: @MCEmperor Yor are right, but a regex for the first assignment?

Comment: if you have to actually check for the characters the user inputs, then this is the best solution. otherwise you will have a very long if, that checks if the first 2 characters, match any non digit. a working regex for your problem would be `"\\D{2}\\d{3}"`

Comment: @IQV Sorry. But I think that the assignment is inappropriate anyway; first, the basics must be taught.

Comment: Yes, that's right! But also with java-basics, this assignment is difficult to do.

Comment: I posted answer with very long if mentioned by @XtremeBaumer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are not aware of `regex` ,I have written this code to iterate by `while` loop and check if each character is a alphabet or digit. User is prompted to provide account number till the valid one is entered

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LinearArray{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isIdValid = false;
        String myId;

        do{
            System.out.println("account ID that consists of 2 letters followed by 3 digits");           
            myId = input.nextLine();
            //Check if the length is 5
            if (myId.length() == 5) {
                //Check first two letters are character and next three are digits
                if(Character.isAlphabetic(myId.charAt(0))
                && Character.isAlphabetic(myId.charAt(1))
                && Character.isDigit(myId.charAt(2))
                && Character.isDigit(myId.charAt(3))
                && Character.isDigit(myId.charAt(4))) {
                    isIdValid = true;
                }
             }
           }while(!isIdValid);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't recreate the `Scanner` multiple times; create it just once before the loop. Also, you don't need the `isIdValid` variable. You can instead use a `do`-`while` loop like so `do { ... } while (myId.length() == 5 && Character.isAlphabetic(myId.charAt(0)) && ...);`

Comment: Sorry, I got the condition wrong. It should be the opposite: `do { ... } while (!(myId.length() == 5 && Character.isAlphabetic(myId.charAt(0)) && ...));`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Yes, I have just created one scanner and changed `while` to `do while` . Left the conditions as it is for more readability

Comment: woah! my teacher did talk about booleans briefly, and I didn't understand how to use it. I was thinking about maybe using a boolean in my code when I woke up today. So you can put methods inside of other methods? Also I didn't know we had isAlphabetic and isDigit, I thought it was only int and char

Comment: why did u write while(!isIdValid) if in the if statements above it it says isIdValid = true;? Why isn't it while(isIdValid) ?

Comment: also why did you choose to use the do while loop instead of a while loop?